# Should every table in my database have a key

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have one table with two columns:

- team_id | not null, unique, primary, auto-increment
- team_name | not null, unique

Each team is a member of one of two conferences and I have the following table for the conference:

- team_id | the id for the team
- 0 or 1, depending on which conference they are a member of.

My question is, the second table doesn't have a primary key. Am I approaching this problem wrong? Does each table need its own primary key? The team_id in the conference table is a reference to the team_id in the teams table.

I apologize if this is worded poorly. I am just beginning to learn this to complement my university learning. If there is anything I can add to clarify my question, please don't hesitate to ask and I will add it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why is the conference membership a separate table?

Comment: I was told to break up everything into the smallest chunks possible. Is that not correct?

Comment: It's probably a bit too small chunk.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Splitting things up like this adds flexibility, but reduces performance. This is something that often comes up.For example if you expect that you will add more things to the second table, and others will also refence that data, then it might make sense to break it off now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is okay to have tables without primary keys. These are called **weak entities** their existence depends on a strong entity. There's a lot of resources online about these but you can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-strong-and-weak-entity/)

Answer (score 1):

I mean in this case the second table is redundant. You can store all data in single table like:

```
create table teams (
    team_id int,
    team_name varchar(255),
    conference_id int2
);
```